# Why would a multilingual site sometimes say "Save (this translation)" and other times say "Save (all translations)"?

Tags: 8, nodes, i18n-l10n

We have a multilingual Drupal 8 site supporting 17 different languages and many more localized versions of those languages.

I have been noticing that sometimes when I am editing a node it says "Save (this translation)" but then other times it says "Save (all translations)".

What is triggering it to act differently at times? Have we configured something wrong with our translations/multilingual setup?

With what we are doing I believe we want them to save independently of each other.

Comment: Sometimes you have fields with values that are same in all translations. Author for example, or a file. That's probably the reason. But first of all you need to find a way to reproduce it. Does it all happen for the same node type filled with the same values?

Answer (score 4):

The text of the submit button depends only on the translation settings of the status field. If the field "Publishing status" is not translatable for the content type, the button says "Save (all translations)".

You can change the language settings for *content types, taxonomy vocabularies, user profiles* here: /admin/config/regional/content-language

Comment: The fields name is "Published".